# How to convert a 13 digit Unix Timestamp to Date and time?

Tags: php, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have this 13 digit timestamp 1443852054000 that i want to convert to date and time but dont succeed. I have tried this codes:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',$item->timestamp);
```

doesnt work for me and also this

```
$unix_time = date('Ymdhis', strtotime($datetime ));
```

and this :

```
$item = strtotime($txn_row['appoint_date']); 
<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time); ?>
```

what should i use?

Comment: it's in milliseconds. just remove the last three zeros and your code will work.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This timestamp is in milliseconds, not in seconds. Divide it by 1000 and use `date` function:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $item->timestamp / 1000);
// e.g
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',1443852054000/1000);
// shows 2015-10-03 02:00:54
```

Comment: i am still  getting this result 1970-01-01 01:00:00

Comment: `var_dump($item->timestamp);`

Comment: I can't say why is it null. You have to check it yourself.

Comment: I think, the divided timestamp should be rounded (to provide date() with an int).

Comment: have i love you  :>

Answer (score 7):

A 13 digit timestamp is used in JavaScript to represent time in milliseconds. In PHP 10 a digit timestamp is used to represent time in seconds. So divide by 1000 and round off to get 10 digits.

```
$timestamp = 1443852054000;
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', floor($timestamp / 1000));
```

Comment: great answer bro, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Because you've a `timestamp` with `13 digits`, you'll have to divide it by `1000`, in order to use it with `DateTime`, i.e.:

```
$ts = 1443852054000 / 1000; // we're basically removing the last 3 zeros
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("U", $ts)->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");
echo $date;
//2015-10-03 06:00:54
```

---

**DEMO**

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d0d01718e0fc02574b401e798aaa201137658acb

---

You may want to [set the default timezone](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to avoid any warnings

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon');
```

---

**NOTE**:

More about `php` date and time at [php the right way](http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time)

Comment: Tell that to Zuckerberg