# What kind of date format is this: 1609078919000?

Tags: python, mysql, json, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have thee following datetime value saved within a json file:

```
"date": 1607230711000,
```

This represents:

```
27.12.2020
```

It does not seem to be a unix timestamp. What kind of format is this?

Would like to convert it in python to be able to save to MySQL DATETIME field.

Comment: Are you sure that it is 2020-12-27? Because assuming it's epoch milliseconds, it would be 2020-12-06T04:58:31Z

Comment: According to https://www.timecalculator.net/milliseconds-to-date it's Dec 5 2020, 23:58:31.

Comment: related: [Converting unix timestamp string to readable date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682748/converting-unix-timestamp-string-to-readable-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a 13 digit epoch time. The last 3 digits being zero you can remove them and treat it as a 10 digit one. The 13 digit form is milliseconds rather than seconds. You can divide it by 1000 to get seconds. This is similar to this question here:

[How to convert a 13 digit Unix Timestamp to Date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926749/how-to-convert-a-13-digit-unix-timestamp-to-date-and-time)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.